# Sum bytes in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I translated this line of code from Delphi:

```
byteSendData[4] := (byteSendData[1] + byteSendData[2] + byteSendData[3]) Mod 256;
```

into this in C#:

```
byteSendData[4] = (byteSendData[1] + byteSendData[2] + byteSendData[3]) % 256;
```

but VS returns me error I can't implicitly convert type 'int' into 'byte'.

Comment: Do an unchecked cast to turn the result to a byte: `byteSendData[4] = unchecked( (byte)(byteSendData[1] + byteSendData[2] + byteSendData[3]) % 256);`

Comment: Also it's more traditional in C# to use `& 0xff` rather than `% 256` for masking.

Comment: I keep getting the same error even with your code: https://i.imgur.com/a2j3eWq.png

Comment: It was missing a set of parenthesis: It should have been `byteSendData[4] = unchecked( (byte)((byteSendData[1] + byteSendData[2] + byteSendData[3]) % 256));`

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, but why that "unchecked" statement is so important? also, you would suggest me to use byteSendData[4] = unchecked( (byte)((byteSendData[1] + byteSendData[2] + byteSendData[3]) & 0xff)); right? what does & do exactly, can you link the manual?

Comment: `unchecked` is probably not necessary since you are restricting the result to 0..255 anyway, so you can omit that. The `&` is a [bitwise AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
byteSendData[4] = Convert.ToByte((byteSendData[1] + byteSendData[2] + byteSendData[3]) % 256);
```

The thing is that you have a byte array *byteSendData* and the modulo calculation returns an integer. So just convert the result to byte. That's all.

Comment: The thing is, the code gives me error even without the modulo part... Anyway I tryed your code and I still get the same error.